# Ubuntu screen error when starting

Tags: kernel, 20.04, screen

I got this error each time I start Ubuntu
I use Ubuntu 20.04 and Kernel 5.4.0
[image]

This is the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` command
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I added the output of lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' command in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Install Nvidia drivers by

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```